# Emoji as part of URL?

Tags: url, emoji

What is that  icon in the URL of WhatsApp Web? I have never seen this in any URLs before.

[image: Google Search result of web.whatsapp.com, showing the icon in the URL]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the [Globe With Meridians](https://emojipedia.org/globe-with-meridians) emoji. It has a unicode symbol of `U+1F310`. It was included in Unicode 6.0 in 2010 and Emoji 1.0 in 2015. I found [this](https://www.charset.org/punycode), which might do this for you in your own URLs. This is the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492) paper on it. [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-intersect/wp/2015/02/23/the-surprisingly-complex-reason-you-never-see-emoji-urls/?utm_term=.db31e1d3b521) also did an article on this.

Comment: Oh nice ! When you suggested the edit, I copied and googled it.

Comment: @a.b it looks like you actually can use this with any emoji. I actually just copied it out of WhatsApps' url.

Comment: Ops! I didn't try that. Thanks.